# Error on the stripe SDK google play store not able to know how to resolve it in React Native

Tags: stripe-payments

Your app com.reel version code 4 includes SDK com.stripe:stripe-android, 14.2.1 which facilitates the transmission or collection of personal and sensitive information. Such behavior must comply with Google Play's Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirements and applicable privacy policy requirements as described in the User Data policy.

Starting from July 12, 2021 midnight (UTC), new app releases containing this SDK version that do not meet the Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirements per the User Data policy will be rejected. You may consider upgrading to 16.9.0, which the SDK provider has recommended for use instead. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

Learn More

Let me Know what is wrong in this I am getting above warning from the play store for the stripe message. React native

Comment: Can you clarify what libraries you're using? What kind of React Native payment libraries does your app use, e.g. tipsi-stripe, or stripe-react-native, or something else?

Comment: I'm using tipsi-stripe and I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Till version 14.2.1 Stripe SDK is not compliant with Google Play's Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirements. They removed non compliant code from version 14.3.0.

So you should not have this issue anymore using version >= ​14.3.0.

Source: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1421---2020-03-26